# Code optimization: Boolean token equivalent to \ifdefempty, which can combine with \OR or \AND

Tags: conditionals, ifthenelse

I'm a new LaTeX user looking for some guidance.

I wish to optimize the following code, since lines 3 and 5 are unnecessarily repeated, because I am using `\ifdefempty{}{}{}`, instead of some Boolean equivalent check inside `\ifthenelse`.

```
\newcommand{\extlink}[3][]{
    \ifdefempty{#3}{%
        \hspace{-.005\textwidth}#2}{% <-- THIS LINE
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{@suppresslinks} \OR \boolean{@forbots}}%
            {\hspace{-.005\textwidth}#2}{% <-- THIS LINE
              %% SOME CODE FOR ELSE BLOCK %%
        }%
    }%
}
```

I understand that this can be easily fixed, if I can use the `\ifdefempty` equivalent Boolean token combined, with `\OR` like this:

```
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@suppresslinks} \OR \boolean{@forbots} \OR \isdefempty{#3} }%
```

As a matter of fact, the following works perfectly with `\isempty`:

```
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@suppresslinks} \OR \boolean{@forbots} \OR \isempty{#3} }%
```

I am seeking guidance in understanding what is an `\isdefempty` equivalent that I can use here. If nothing exists out-of-the-box, how can I create a macro that'll return a Boolean true or false, capable of combining with `\OR` or `\AND`?

Substantial code refactoring might not be feasible in my use case, as this pattern is used across a large codebase. Accordingly, I prefer some `\isdefempty` Boolean token solution.

To demonstrate, this is how i am calling `\extlink`:

```
\extlink[]{I love Tex Exchange...}{\texurl}
```

where the `\texurl` is defined as:

```
\newcommand{\texurl}{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}
```

and I require `\isdefempty` specifically to check when the definition is empty:

```
\newcommand{\texurl}{}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/134641)!

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using the [`xifthen`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xifthen) package, as shown below. In particular, you can use that package's `\isundefined` instead of `\ifdefempty`, which can then be combined using the Boolean logic you require. While those two commands are not strictly equivalent, I believe it is likely sufficient in your case (refer to the [`xifthen` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xifthen/xifthen.pdf) for details).

```
\usepackage{xifthen}


\newcommand{\extlink}[3][]{
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{#3} \AND \( \boolean{@suppresslinks} \OR \boolean{@forbots} \)}%
        {\hspace{-.005\textwidth}#2}{%
            %% SOME CODE FOR ELSE BLOCK %%
    }%
}
```

Comment: I looked up at `xifthen` documentation. What seems to be working is `\ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}`. I don't know if that's a right way to do or there's some caveat my lack of experience is unable to see. Also, I don't understand why `\isempty` returns false in this situation?

Comment: @BhaveshDiwan I suspect both commands return false because `#3` contains `\relax` or some equivalent? It would help if you could edit your question to provide *all* of your code, as a  [Minimum Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134641).

Comment: @BhaveshDiwan I also find that `\isempty` sometimes provides a surprising answer, because its concept of "empty" is not the same as mine. So I do not use it. Your use of `\ifthenelse` is how I do it. You might also do `\AND` with a space (not just empty braces) within `\ifthenelse`, if there is the possibility that "space is empty".